# Having trouble creating a wrapper function for api calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

So essentially I have a pattern I will like to use throughout my api calls. It's essentially a `try catch finally` block where I dispatch a series of actions. Instead of copying and pasting this pattern everywhere, I'd like to create a wrapper function where all I pass in are the necessary parameters, api function, and dispatch actions.

My try call block function looks like this:

```js
export function getTokenAPI(username, password) {
  return async function action(dispatch) {
    try {

      dispatch(loadingActions.loadingInProgress(true));


      const { data } = await API.authGetToken(username, password);
      const { success } = data;

      console.log('get token api data', data);
      if (success) {


        dispatch(setData(data));

        dispatch(setTokenSuccess());
      } else if (!success) {
        const { errorMessage } = data;
        throw Error(errorMessage || 'You broke it, not my fault');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(errorActions.addError(e.message));
      dispatch(errorActions.removeError());
    } finally {
      dispatch(loadingActions.loadingInProgress(false));
    }
  };
}
```

So the wrapper I tried to create looks like this:

```js
function wrapper(apiFunction, dispatchAction) {
  return async function action(dispatch) {
    try {
      dispatch(loadingActions.loadingInProgress(true));
      const { data } = await apiFunction(arg1, arg2);
      const { success } = data;
      if (success) {
        dispatch(dispatchAction(data));
      } else if (!success) {
        const { errorMessage } = data;
        throw Error(errorMessage || 'meh');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(errorActions.addError(e.message));
      dispatch(errorActions.removeError());
    } finally {
      dispatch(loadingActions.loadingInProgress(false));
    }
  };
}
```

With that I can eventually just run

```
wrapper(apiFunction(username, password), setData)
```

but I'm getting a `TypeError Cannot read property type of undefined`. I'm wondering if I'm going about this the right way at all.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrapper` is a `high order function` which expects two arguments `apiFunction` and `dispatchAction` and `return` an `action creator` which expects an action and have to be wrapped in a `dispatch` instance. So you should use `wrapper` like this

```
const Component = () =>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onSubmit = () =>{
        dispatch(wrapper(apiFunction, dispatchAction)(action))
    }
}
```

`wrapper(apiFunction, dispatchAction)` evaluates to another function which expects an argument `action` and need to be explicitly executed. Is the equivalent of

```
const onSubmit = () =>{
    const actionCreator = wrapper(apiFunction, dispatchAction)
    dispatch(actionCreator(action))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this by editing my wrapper a little bit more and by using Dupocas' answer as inspiration (needed to use dispatch).

Here's my wrapper and here's how I'm using it:

**apiWrapper**

```js
import { loadingActions } from '_ducks/loading';
import { errorActions } from '_ducks/error';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const os = Platform === 'ios' ? 'iPhone' : 'Android';

const { loadingInProgress } = loadingActions;
const { addError, removeError } = errorActions;

export default function apiWrapper(
  apiFunction,
  dispatchActionData,
  dispatchActionStatus,
) {
  return async function action(dispatch) {
    try {
      dispatch(loadingInProgress(true));
      const { data } = await apiFunction;
      const { success } = data;
      console.log('D A T A', data);

      if (success) {
        dispatchActionData && dispatch(dispatchActionData(data));
        dispatchActionStatus && dispatch(dispatchActionStatus());
      } else if (!success) {
        const { errorMessage } = data;
        throw Error(
          errorMessage || `Sounds like a problem with your ${os} device`,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(addError(e.message));
      dispatch(removeError());
    } finally {
      dispatch(loadingInProgress(false));
    }
  };
}
```

**apiWrapper use**

```
export function submitLogIn(username, password) {
  return function action(dispatch) {
    dispatch(
      apiWrapper(
        API.getSTUFF(username, password),
        setUserData,
        setTokenSuccess,
      ),
    );
  };
}
```